# How to count character of a string in assembly not use 0Ah/int21h

Tags: assembly

I want to know another way to count character of a string not use 0Ah/int21h. Thank for your help :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bassembly%5D+strlen

Comment: Write some code to do it yourself?  That's a super approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a register pointing to the first character of the string and another register set to zero.

Loop until the contents of the first register are the `NUL` character (or whatever terminator you want), incrementing both those registers.

At the end, the second register will have the length.

In pseudo-asm-code (since it's very likely this is classwork):

```
    push  r1, r3                 ; preserve registers
    load  r1, address-of-string
    xor   r2, r2                 ; xor a number with itself gives 0
startloop:
    load  r3, [r1]               ; get memory contents
    beq   endloop                ; if NUL, we're at string end
    inc   r1                     ; otherwise incr both and loop back
    inc   r2
    bra   startloop
endloop:
    pop   r3, r1                ; restore registers
                                ; r2 now has the length.
```

Your job is to now turn that into real assembly code (most likely x86 given your mention of `int 21h`).

Comment: yeah it's my homework :D i try to find out another way but my code is too long. tks you again

Comment: BTW, `xor same,same` is only a good zeroing idiom on x86.  On many other architectures, including ARM, [it's architecturally required to carry a dependency on the input register (to preserve memory_order_consume semantics)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222999/convert-c-to-assembly-with-predicated-instruction/37224546#comment61983585_37224546), so `mov r2, 0` is the same size (or smaller on ARM Thumb2) and significantly better.  But clearly you were just trying to write x86 asm in disguise, so +1 :)